# Solr; read specific data

Tags: solr, nutch

Is there anyway to read specific data in solr? For example; using nutch I crawled [http://www.amazon.com/Jessica-Simpson-Womens-Asymmetrical-X-Small/dp/B018MRT16Q/ref=lp_13906149011_1_3?m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&s=apparel&ie=UTF8&qid=1455828781&sr=1-3&nodeID=13906149011](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B018MRT16Q); 
then with solr I want it to search through and just display the price of the jacket.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If you only want to search and return a particluar field, you can explicitly search on that field using `<fieldname>:<query>` and to only return some particular fields use the `fl` parameter `fl=Price`.

So your solr query should be something like this:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=Price:500&fl=Price
```

Additionally if you want to search over and return multiple fields, use the `qf` parameter along with the `edismax` parser like this:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=500&fl=Price,Name&defType=edismax&qf=Price,Name
```